# If a game admits a unique Nash equilibirum, does common knowledge of rationality implies Nash equilibirum?

Tags: game-theory, reference-request, nash-equilibrium

In a highly controversial paper by Robert Aumann(see [here](http://www.ma.huji.ac.il/raumann/pdf/36.pdf)), it is stated as a theorem:

> In PI games, common knowledge of rationality implies backward induction.

If we stick to the strong and controversial definition of rationality in the paper

> Rationality of a player means that he is a habitual payoff maximizer:
>   that no matter where he finds himself,
>   at which vertex,he will
>   not knowingly continue with a strategy that yields him less than he could
>   have gotten with a different strategy.

Can we have some other implication, like, If a game admits a unique Nash equilibirum, does common knowledge of rationality implies Nash equilibirum?

Comment: The first quote should be "In perfect information games, common ...", which makes it much less controversial.

Comment: @TheAlmightyBob You're right! The controversies are different in two settings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. In static games, common knowledge of rationality is equivalent to rationalizability. Bernheim, in "[Rationalizable Strategic Behavior](http://www.econ.yale.edu/~dirkb/teach/pdf/b/bernheim/1984%20rationalizable%20strategic%20behavior.pdf)" (Econometrica, July 1984) gives an example on page 1012 in Figure 1 of a normalform game in which there is a unique Nash equilibrium, yet multiple strategies are rationalizable.

Comment: You are looking at David Pearce's paper, but you should look at Doug Bernheim's paper in the same issue of Econometrica.

Comment: My bad. Sorry : )